# How to Import .eml in Outlook VSTO AddIn

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

How can i import .eml files into Outlook Native Emails So i may store them as local storage.
I have .eml files which need to be properly parsed and imported into Outlook Native Emails.

Comment: Though nothing wrong with answering your own question, it kinda looks weird to tag a question with a technology or API (in this case `outlook-redemption`) that under normal circumstances a poster posting a question would not know.  It only makes sense from the point of view from someone posting an _answer_.  If they knew it, they wouldn't ask.  It's a bit like someone asking _"Which airline has never crashed"_ and tagging it with `qantas`.  I'll get back in my box now. ;)

Comment: I suppose Admins can always update the question headline or whatever they think needs updation.

Comment: Well you could expand on your question a bit.  Ignoring the fact you are answering your own question, the question as stands is **too broad**. [ask]

Comment: Removed tag that's not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using *Redemption Import Feature*.

```
var inbox = RDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
RDOMail mailitem = inbox.Items.Add();
mailitem.Import(@"e:\\test.eml", RedemptionSaveAsType.olRFC822);
mailitem.Save();
```

What this code does is gets the default Inbox folder and creates a empty email item. Then the import function retrieves the .eml file and parses into the email. we can save this to inbox then.

If we are using any Webservices then by fetching the .eml with HttpClient and then import and save it.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, after creating an instance of the Redemption.RDOSession object, set its MAPIOBJECT property to Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT to make sure you are using the same MAPI session as Outlook (since your code is running in a COM addin). You might also want to set the RDOMail.Sent property to true before calling Save().